# Hide Seconds Counter on Flipclock.js

Tags: javascript, css, flipclock

I'm currently working on a project where the requirement is to use flipclock.js to create an HH:MM counter.

I'm using the `HourlyCounter` clock face. Does anyone know how I could hide the seconds part?

Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE

After using @Rahul's css, i've gotten the following:

[image]

### UPDATE2

I've got an image of the inspected element if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Since you dont provide any code/demo Im taking reference from http://flipclockjs.com/

here you go...

you can use below code, this will hide seconds part

```
.flip-clock-divider.seconds , .flip-clock-divider.seconds ~ .flip.play {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

then you may need to adjust width accordingly like

```
.header .clock{
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! It kinda works. I'll attach an image of what I got. Could you please help me with this? :)

Comment: sure, can you show me snapshot of source code of how it looks while you inspect element that last 9 which you want to hide

Comment: I've added that image. :)

Comment: I've added an answer below that will fix your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify wether or not to show seconds via the options, when you initiate the clock. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var clock;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock',
                showSeconds: false
            });
        });
</script>
```

If you are unsure how to use it, there's an example file included in the package that you download on their website, "examples/twenty-four-hour-clock-without-seconds.html"